# Rewriting to address on postfix local aliases

Tags: email, postfix, domain-name

I was running into the common problem that mail for "root" on my system was having $mydomain appended, and because $mydomain is not in $mydestination, the mail was being sent to our central mail server as "root@domain."

I cannot add $mydomain to $mydestination, because if I understand it correctly, that would mean all mail addressed to $mydomain would be looked up locally, and if an alias does not exist, delivery would fail.

So, I followed these instructions:

[Delivering some, but not all accounts locally](http://www.postfix.org/STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README.html#some_local)

which seems to have resolved the problem.  Mail for "root" is now expanded according to /etc/aliases and delivered to the non-local address I desire.  The one oddity however is that the "To:" address still reads "root@domain."  Is there any way I can get the "To" address to be the one that the alias directed its delivery?  So for example, if my alias says that mail for "root" should go to "hostname-admin@domain" is there any way the "To" address can be rewritten as "hostname-admin@domain?"  Currently it still shows as "root@domain."

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the smtp_generic_maps Postfix feature.

The steps to achieve this are explained [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-postfix-masquerade-change-email-mail-address.html)